# Bootstrap 3.3.7 - Will CDN (maxcdn) Support end for Bootstrap and will I be forced to migrate to bootstrap 4?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am developing a webpage for work using Bootstrap 3.3.7 supported via CDN (See links below). My knowledge of HTML, JavaScript’s, CSS etc.. is limited and What I have created so far is really good. I am worried that I am basing my page on CND support for bootstrap version 3.3.7 is a bad idea.

Questions;

1. Will the CDN support ever end?
2. When a new version of bootstrap is released will I be forced to migrate or can I continue to use 3.3.7 version indefinitely?

Comment: it all depends on the CDN provider

Comment: is there any reason not to copy the library and load it from your own server? In many cases, applications are compiling all the js code into a single file, especially, libraries, cause loading 10 small files is longer then to load a bigger file even with content overhead, cause its network latency that often costs most of the delay.

Comment: 1. It depends on the provider of CDN
2. You can still use it but I'm pretty sure that they will not update it because a later version is already available

My question:
Why not just download the bootstrap library and use it instead of using CDN?

Comment: 1. Most common CDN's are 99.9% uptime, the most popular is maxcdn for Bootstrap. 2. you are not forced to update your Bootstrap version, that is why in your CDN URL you can choose ANY Bootstrap version (even legacy ones). so you are safe with that versioning thing.

Comment: [ https://cdnjs.com/libraries/twitter-bootstrap/ ] check the version they provide from bootstrap 1.4.1 to 4.0.0 
so don't worry about end of cdn.. and maxcnd also provide bootstrap cdn's from version 2.0.4 to 4.0.0 [ https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/2.0.4/css/bootstrap.min.css ]

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to be forced to migrate to BS4. Then get the MAXCDN files to your local & call your styles & scripts from there. Steps you should follow:

> Note: below steps are demonstrated for CSS only. You need to do that to JS file as well

1. Open your MAXCDN link in your browser address bar, say for example:

   https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css
2. Now copy the entire code that you can see .. `Ctrl + A` > `Ctrl + C`
3. Now create a file on your local project under say css folder & name it whatever you want, say `bs3.3.7.min.css`(make sure it has `.min.css` as the extension for CSS).
4. Now paste the entire code you copied to the CSS file you just created.
5. Finally you need to just change the `<link href="/link/to/bs3.3.7.min.css">` in your HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Answers: 
1: It all depends on the provider of CDN 
2: No one is going to forced you to use latest version, they might provide updated version a new URL again but it all depends on CDN provider

for safer side you can store those bootstrap files in your server and use it instead of CDN this way you will always have right version of files for your website